# BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210119)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, rbenv, ruby-2.7

I'm using rbenv  and in Ec2 instance I'm trying to install a ruby different version but when I execute

```
rbenv install 2.7.2
```

following errors occur.

```
Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 20.04 using ruby-build 20210119)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20210217075101.162094.zs1iDJ
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20210217075101.162094.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling mjit.c
compiling mjit_compile.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
gcc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:421: parse.o] Error 1
```

meanwhile, my system is using the default ruby version

```
  ubuntu@ip-112-34-9-342:~$ rbenv versions
 * system (set by /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/version)
```

I don't confirm it is a space issue or something else, space information is listed below.

```
 ubuntu@ip-112-34-9-342:~$ free
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:         486776      177636       89396         800      219744      287744
    Swap:          0           0           0
```

Comment: Probably out of memory. 512MB is not enough to compile it all.

Comment: @tadman how can I find my remaining ram? the upper statistics show my ram or my memory?

Comment: `free -m` should have > 1GB free to start.

Comment: thankyou my free is 77 :(

Comment: That's nowhere near enough. You either need a bigger instance, or you need to find a pre-built 2.7.2 binary installer. Is there a package for Ubuntu that's 2.7.2 or close enough? Could you build on another machine and deploy there? This is where Docker containers are super handy if that's an option.

Comment: All about free memory is nonsense. I have 62 GB of free RAM. That not enough either?

Answer (score 5):

Run the following -

```
$ sudo apt install gcc make curl libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
```

You are welcome.